# Getting a strange result about speed of block sliding on a rough wedge

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, friction

> To Find the speed of both block and wedge when the block just reaches ground (both block and wedge are initially at rest)?

[image: the wedge block problem]

*(the black block at bottom is not present there, it is just future position of the red block.)*

---

## **Getting a strange result:**

```
using momentum conservation on system in x-direction
 v1 = 4v2

using work energy theorem with both block and wedge as a system-
 mgH = 1/2 (m v1^2) + 1/2 (4m v2^2)

using above two equations -
v1 = 4 √(gH / 10)
```

> ## It does not depend on friction

so v1 does not depend on friction. But if we increase the coefficient of friction between block and wedge it sounds really strange that the block still gets that speed.

Is my solution wrong? or if it's correct then how it gets same speed even after increased opposing force (is it related to motion of wedge?).

Comment: Hello! It is preferable to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the equation for conservation of energy, you have implicitly assumed that there are non non-conservative forces (such as friction) acting on any objects in the system.  If there was friction acting between the block and the wedge, this equation would be
$$
mgh = \frac{1}{2} m_1 v_1^2 + \frac{1}{2} m_2 v_2^2 - W_\text{fr}
$$
where $W_\text{fr}$ is the combined amount of work done by friction on the block and on the wedge.  (Note that $W_\text{fr} < 0$, which implies that $v_1$ and $v_2$ will be reduced relative to the frictionless case.)

Comment: oh yes, you are right thanks. initially i thought that all internal forces cancel so work should also cancel

Comment: The work of the internal forces can change the kinetic energy. The work-energy theoem for systems of particles states that the change in KE is equal to the total work done by external and internal forces. The internal forces cannot change the total momentum.